# Response text from AJAX is blank

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to do an AJAX call and I'm getting a successful (200) response but the response text is blank.

I've looked at several other SO answered to this question but none of them seemed to work.

```
<form id="status-code-form" v-on:submit="processStatusForm">
<input type="text" id="status-code-url" v-model="ajInput" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
var appForm = new Vue({
el: '#status-code-form',
// our data
data: {
ajInput: ''
},
// our methods
 methods: {
processStatusForm: function(e) {

e.preventDefault();

// start ajax

if (this.ajInput !== "") {

var newInputtedText = this.ajInput;
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('POST', './processes/check-url-code.php', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.onload = function() {
if (xhr.status === 200 && xhr.readyState === 4) {
console.log("Response text was successfull" + xhr.responseText);
}
else if (xhr.status !== 200) {
alert('Request failed.  Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
}
};
var data = {action: 'content_fetch', inputtedText: newInputtedText };
xhr.send('action=content_fetch&inputtedText=' + newInputtedText);


} // end if input was empty

} // end process form

} // end methods
});

</script>
```

In my PHP file, it's very simple:

```
<?php

function content_fetch() { 

echo "hello";


}
```

I would think that the response text is equal to "hello", but it's blank. I just get the console log of "Response text was successfull".

Comment: php functions dont run themselves, your php code needs to explicitly call it (unless using some php framework that adds that, but you havent mentioned any)

Comment: @PatrickEvans Can't believe I overlooked that one. Thanks!